# Retrieve an element of a list that satisfy a condition

Tags: dart

This is my model class:

```
class Contact {
  String name;
  String email;
  int phoneNo;

  Contact(this.name, this.email, this.phoneNo);
}
```

Suppose I have a list of contacts like below:

```
List<Contact> contacts = [
  new Contact('John', 'john@c.com', 002100),
  new Contact('Lily', 'lily@c.com', 083924),
  new Contact('Abby', 'abby@c.com', 103385),
];
```

I want to get `John`'s phone number from `contacts` `List`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`singleWhere` throws if there are duplicates or no element that matches.

An alternative is `firstWhere` with `orElse` https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html

```
var urgentCont = contacts.firstWhere((e) => e.name == 'John', orElse: () => null);
print(urgentCont?.phoneNo?.toString()?.padLeft(6, '0') ?? '(not found)');//Output: 002100
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it using [`singleWhere`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/singleWhere.html):

```
var urgentCont = contacts.singleWhere((e) => e.name == 'John');
print(urgentCont.phoneNo.toString().padLeft(6, '0'));//Output: 002100
```

> `singleWhere(bool test(E element)) → E` Returns the **single element** that
>   satisfies `test`.

And there is some other methods in [List class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/List-class.html). As a example [`where()`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Iterable/where.html):

> `where(bool test(E element)) → Iterable<E>` Returns a new lazy Iterable
>   with **all elements** that satisfy the predicate `test`.

**Update:**

`singleWhere()` throws an error when there is no matching elements(`Bad state: No element`). And if there are duplicates, will throw `Bad state: Too many elements`

So, the best one is `firstWhere` according to @GunterZochbauer(refer his answer)

Comment: "the best one" is relative :D It depends on what you try to accomplish. If you are 100 positive the list has to contain exactly one item that matches, then `singleWhere` is a good idea, because it throws an exception if that assumption doesn't hold - which indicates a serious bug if you build your code based on that assumption. On the other side if you for example get some JSON code from some cloud API that is unlikely to follow a fixed structure then `singleWhere` is risky because it probably is expected to fail regularly.